# Rails API has_many relationship not being displayed in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relational-database

I am implementing a Following / Follower relationship, for User model. When I navigate to the /users route only the users followers are being included in the users JSON object. I have a feeling it has something to do with the pluralization, but I included a source in the has_many so i'm not really sure.

However when I enter the rails console i'm able to access user.followers and user.following and it properly lists all the users following and followers respectively.

```
#/users/10
{
  "id": 10,
  "username": "guest",
  "companies": [... ],
  "rides": [.. . ],
  "messages": [  ...],
  "forums": [... ],
  "followers": [... ],
  #following is not listed here, but should be
}
```

```
#models\User.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord

   .
   .
   .

  def follow(other_user)

   active_relationships.create(followed_id: other_user.id)

  end

  # Unfollows a user.
  def unfollow(other_user)
   active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy
   # byebug
  end

  # Returns true if the current user is following the other user.
  def following?(other_user)
   following.include?(other_user)
  end

  has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Friendship",
                                   foreign_key: :follower_id,
                                   dependent:   :destroy

   has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Friendship",
                                   foreign_key: :followed_id,
                                     dependent:   :destroy
   has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
   has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower


end
```

```
#serializers/user_serializer.rb
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  .
  .
  .

  has_many :followers
  has_many :following

end
```

```
#models/friendship.rb
class Friendship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :follower, foreign_key: "follower_id", class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, foreign_key: "followed_id", class_name: "User"
  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

```
#schema
  create_table "friendships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "follower_id"
    t.integer "followed_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["followed_id"], name: "index_friendships_on_followed_id"
    t.index ["follower_id", "followed_id"], name: "index_friendships_on_follower_id_and_followed_id", unique: true
  end
```

Comment: If you can see the expected result in your console queries, this is probably because of what data you are collecting in the controller, and/or how you are serializing that into JSON. Could you add your controller code?

Comment: Has many relationships need to be pluralized, ie `has_many :followings`